# Can I use Mathematica to translate a English word to a Chinese characters?

Tags: interpreter

I'm Chinese. I want to translate an `Entity` name to Chinese characterc. What should I do? Can I use *Mathematica* to translate a English word to a Chinese characters?

Comment: What do you mean by `Entity` name? Something like `Liu Cixin` to `刘慈欣`?

Comment: @Felix yeah,like as your example.I want to translate the `Entity` name,but if possible i want to translate a arbitrary  English word to Chinese Character

Comment: You could use google translate with Import or so. http://translate.google.com/m/translate#en/zh-CN/ape translates the word  "ape" into simplified Chinese. All you have to do is parse the result.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries don't you know?everybody cannot use Google in China.

Comment: I know, but you didn't tell you were in China, just that you're Chinese. Well, then you have to look for a translation service that is accessible to you. As far as I know neither Mathematica, nor Wolfram|Alpha do translations.

Comment: You may try to use http://www.bing.com/translator/. There are plenty of translation sites available.

Comment: What is the purpose of the translation? Depending on what you need, *Mathematica*'s `WordData` may be of help by giving you a definition of an English word. Try something like `WordData["house", "Definitions"]`. That is of course not a translation, but it may help you nonetheless, if you are trying to understand what the word means.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries Hi, Sjoerd C. de Vries. I can't find the translated word in the source page of  translate.google.com/m/translate#en/zh-CN/ape. I think simple parse will not gonna work. Could you confirm this?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries actually I can't find translated results in the source page in all translation service I have tried at the moment